# select the text in a text field when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can you so that the text in the text field is selected when the user clicks on the text input field?

i have used this code:

```
  $("input[type=text]").focus(function() {
      $(this).select();
  });
```

but it doesnt work in safari. and in FF it works sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `select()` method in jQuery simply triggers the select event on all matched objects.  You need to do something fancier if you want to manipulate the selected range of text in a textbox.  Modern browsers behave differently here.

The following code should work in Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari, and Opera:

```
<input type="text" id="textBox" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function textBox_click(ev) {
        if (this.createTextRange) {
            // This is for IE and Opera.
            range = this.createTextRange();
            range.moveEnd('character', this.value.length);
            range.select();
        } else if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            // This is for Mozilla and WebKit.
            this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);
        }
    }

    $('#textBox').click(textBox_click);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("input[type=text]").focus().select();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Opera, FF, IE

```
$("input[type=text]").focus(function() {
    this.select();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use this in my HTML:

```
... onclick="this.select()"
```